# table div is not fixing into the parent div. unnecessary scroll bars shown.

Tags: css

I am showing a table which has 8 rows as a preview. but it not fixed into its parent div.

[image: previewScreen of my application]

I saw css options like overflow,height, width...etc in the css-code of this html. I changed their values but no use.

could you let me know all possibilities to fix this issue.

thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please share your html and css code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that are to be understood. What is table div?? Is there is there a table inside a div which is again inside a div?

Please try

```
table-layout : fixed
```

for more information follow the  below links

[W3schools table fixed layout](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp)

[Css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/)

Comment: I fixed this myself - I aligned width and heights. thankU